# Cannot access function variables placed in fancytree source nodes from it's activate method

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

If my fancytree has a source configuration as:

```
 source: [{
                    title: "Item1",
                    key: "1",
                    myFunc: function (item) {
                        return 'function';
                    },
                    myString: 'string'
                }]
```

On activate, when examining data.node.data, it returns only the mystring data:

```
{myString: "string"}
```

How would I be able to access function variables (in this example, call myFunc()) on activation?

Comment: Could you make the example, a bit more concrete, so we can better understand why you need a separate callback *per node*?

Comment: An example could be, selective filtering by passing the function as a callback to a filter process, so, myFunc could be: function(item){return item.color === 'red' && item.date > yesterday;} and the main activate would be passToFilter(node.data.myFunc).   Without using functions I'd have to basically do a switch statement, e.g. if (data.node.title === "Item1") return item.color === 'red' && item date > yesterday.   Having the function on the node makes maintenance and figuring out the actual filter easier, rather than having to look at the activate method to see what it really does.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are filtered out when copying custom attributes to `node.data`.
However it might be more efficient anyway to have those functions only once, i.e. convert the method-style call:

```js
res = node.myFunc(item);
```

to a separate stand-alone function like:

```js
res = myFunc(node, item);
```

Comment: I already know I can just pass as a parameter, but it is very inconvenient to build a list of all possible values and comparables via strings / switch statements as opposed to direct requests via a function, as these items are not necessarily similar in their actions and have various complexities.  I may parse the source and see if I can customize / unfilter functions from the nodes.  There is no reason to filter these out, as it just hurts functionality.